# this.Master.Master.findcontrol() error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I am trying to access the Master page that is Master of the page's Master. I am using the following syntax to do it..

```
this.Master.Master.FindControl("abc");
```

However this generates the following error.

> The type 'ASP.masterpage_master' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'App_Web_masterpage.master.cdcab7d2.fhyd3fxv, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I have included the at mastertype attribute properly on each nested master page.

Comment: do you have nested master page?

Comment: yes it is nested master pages..  @AmitSingh